# Map $w(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ for $0<|z|<1$ is Conformal

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

**Question**   Map from punctured disc $$D^*:=\lbrace z\in\mathbb{C}:0<|z|<1\rbrace$$ to a domain $P$
$$P:=\lbrace w\in\mathbb{C}:1/2<\Re(w), w\neq 1\rbrace$$ defined as
$$w:D^* \to P $$
$$w(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2} $$ is Conformal.

**Attempt**
$$w:D^* \to P $$
$$w(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2} $$
$w(z)$ is analytic for $z\in D^*$
$$w'(z)= \frac{-2z}{(1+z^2)^2}$$
$$w'(z)\neq 0 \ \forall \  z\in D^*$$
Also $D^*$ is connected.
Hence the map is conformal.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is a problem with your definitions : your $P$ is not a half-plane (Hint : make a picture of it !). And your function does not take values in your $P$ (but it does take values in some half-plane ; which one ?).
Also, can you explain what you want to show, and using what ? Because there is a very short answer to your question (your function is holomorphic, hence conformal), but I suspect it is not the one you are after.

Comment: @J. Darné Thanks. It is an infinite strip. But the map is correct.

Comment: No it is not that analytic means conformal. On the unit disc $|z|<1 $ $f(z)=1/1+z^2$ is analytic but not conformal as $f'(0)=0$

Comment: Sorry, holomorphic with non-vanishing derivative

Comment: @J. Darné But it is a punctured disc. Then also it is true? Nothing will  change?

Comment: My function does take values on P. Can you see this?

Comment: If $z = ti$, with $t$ a real number approaching $1$, $f(z)$ is real and approches $+ \infty$, so $f$ does not take values in this strip.

Comment: Conformal is a local property (a function is conformal at a point if it does not change angles between curves crossing at this point), so regardless of the shape of your domain, if $f$ is analytic near a point (with non-vanishing derivative), it will be conformal at this point.

Comment: @J. Darné What is the image of Puncture disc under this map???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123726/discussion-between-j-darne-and-kiara).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to look at this, in my opinion, is to look at your map as the composite of 3 functions:

- First, the square map $z \mapsto z^2$,
- Next, the translation $z \mapsto z + 1$,
- Then, the inverse map $z \mapsto 1/z$.

The derivative of the first one is multiplication by $2$, which is a homothety, and it is conformal. The derivative of the second one is multiplication by $1$, even better. Since a composite of conformal maps is conformal, you only need to know that the inverse map is. And it is, since it is $\mathbb C$-derivable: its differential at a point $z$ is multiplication by the non-trivial complex number $-1/z^2$, and multiplication by a non-trivial complex number is a homothety (which is the reason why holomorphic maps with non-vanishing derivative are conformal).

Comment: Thanks a lot dear.

Comment: check mark and +1 for you.

Comment: It should be "holmorphic maps with non zero derivative are conformal"

Comment: Forgot again. Thanks !

Comment: Welcome!. Anytime